# How to make a FA from regular expression with span match?

Tags: c#, regex, finite-automata, fsm

I want to make a finite automation or finite state machine from a regular expression. The FA should shift when received a specific character. For example, state A would shift to state B when received `'x'` or `'y'`, which is represented as `[xy]` in a regular expression. In this case I can use a hash set to quickly decide if the coming character is `'x'` or `'y'`. However, there are spans in regular expressions, like `[a-z]` and `[\u4E00-\u9FEA]`. It may be hard to use a hash set for a span, especially a large one. I would have to compare it.

Things get much more complicated when both spans and discrete alternatives appear, e.g. `[a-z079\u4E00-\u9FEA]`. What is the efficient way to match input in this case?

Comment: I would just use the string split method around the backslash character.  Then use a dictionary for look up.  I've done lots of state machines.  The lookup is current state : action : Next State.

Comment: Do you mean that add all 20970 characters in `[\u4E00-\u9FEA]` to dictionary?

Comment: If that what it takes.  I do not no the details.  A state table must have all combinations of old state - action : new state.  You may be able to do state reduction to simplify.  But that state table must be complete.  You can implement a state table with a dictionary, but there may be better methods.  Do not know.  The dictionary may be Dictionary [old state - action, new state] .  Or Dictionary<old state,List<new states>> : New State.  So if you had 8 actions each action would be one of the 8 values in the List<New State>